# Get directed acyclic graph showing OpenMP tasks

Tags: openmp

Is there an automated way to get the task graph from a given OpenMP code with `depend` clauses? The task graph should show the tasks as vertices and data dependencies as directed edges.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Probably not, but check out OpenMP profiling tools

More complicated answer...
You can potentially write your own tool to achieve some of this using the OMPT interfaces which allow you to log events of interest. However, mapping a task dependence from the runtime representation (a pointer value) back to something meaningful is likely to be "fun".
You could check out Score-P and TAU; they may have support (as may Intel VTune).